# Windows 7 pro (64 bit) installation does not recognize Samsung EVO 850 SSD on an H81M-P33 board

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, drivers, ssd, motherboard

So I got a new computer with the [MSI  H81M-P33](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/H81M-P33.html) mainboard, plugged in my Samsung EVO 850 SSD ([MZ-75E250B](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/memory-storage/MZ-75E250B/AM)) into SATA and tried to boot from the Windows 7 CD. The installation fails to recognize the SSD and now I'm wondering if I need to load some drivers during the installation. What drivers do I need?

[image]

I found [this archive](http://support.lenovo.com/de/en/downloads/ds100709) but it consists of a Setup.exe that needs to be run on an installed system. Can I somehow extract the driver and put it on a USB drive to load during Windows installation?

Comment: Can you see the drive in your BIOS?

Comment: Yes, I can even choose it as the boot device.

Comment: I'd advise you to try resolving the issue by [resetting BIOS](http://www.wikihow.com/Reset-Your-BIOS), @Pavel! This will get your BIOS settings back to factory defaults, so you will need to re-configure the SATA mode for the SSD in AHCI. You might also check if you have the latest SATA controller & Chipset drivers for your motherboard. Give it a try and let us know how it goes! Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this [KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2990941/update-to-add-native-driver-support-in-nvm-express-in-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2) to your installation kit and it will be detected.

After installation, apply [this fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3087873/-0x0000007e-stop-error-after-you-install-hotfix-2990941-in-windows-7-sp1-or-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1) if needed.